# Чем отличается объявление полей и переменных в методе

Tags: c#, переменные, конструктор, field

Возможно глупый вопрос, но. Почему так происходит? У меня есть предположение, что причина этому конструктор по умолчанию, который инициализирует поля, а переменные очевидно нет. Почему было не сделать так, что бы переменные при объявлении получали дефолтное значение? В отладчике в этих переменных есть значения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А смысл? Никогда не знаешь куда может завести выполнение метода. Метод может отработать прямо тут и прямо сейчас с использованием всех объявленных ресурсов и с фразой: ``зашли и вышли, делов на 20нс``, а может быть страх и ужас с кучей if'ов, бессмысленным выделением памяти, обращением к внешним ресурсам, обработкой ошибок, итд... Тут уже может потребоваться подложить соломку и объявить переменную заранее, и инициализировать её только тогда, когда и надо использовать.

Comment: добавь в вопрос код в виде текста, а не картинки

Comment: [Why do local variables require initialization, but fields do not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30816496/2881286)